# Angular dynamic FormGroupName outside of *ngFor is not updated to selected index

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Replicated here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x5eoac?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I'm expecting the selected `FormGroupName`, i.e `...[formGroupName]='selectedIndex'`
to be re-rendered each time `selectedIndex` has changed

to my dismay, the component remains reactive to its' initial group name and does not serve anything else, even when manually detecting changes using `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges`

Thank you for reading

Comment: When will you change value of selected variable ?

Comment: @GRD on clicking a child of the *ngFor, e.g `<div... (click)='selectedIndex = index'`

Comment: By clicking fromGroup is getting changed. But what it means `to be re-rendered` each time ?

Comment: I mean, the `formGroup` may be logically changed, but it does not change in the UI. meaning - the standalone box still serves the old selected `formGroup`

Comment: Means, when you click on list div part then selected index has changed to list part but same is not changed inside `<div [formGroupName]="select.selected">
        <input type="text" formControlName="url" />
      </div>` this part ? right ? @shuk

Comment: Exactly. realizing it is currently not dynamic, I encapsulated the selected formGroup in another `*ngFor` and presenting the selected `formGroup` with an `*ngIf` so a div gets rendered and the formGroup itself remains as initially assigned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239347/discussion-between-grd-and-shuk).

Comment: workaround here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jkygz4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html